# Keras saving weights of individual layers instead of a model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm currently trying to create multiple models that will reuse certain layers, including their weights.
I've achieved this by creating a list table that initializes these layers, then call them when creating each individual models.

```
column = []
column.append(Conv2D(self.out_filters, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu'))
column.append(Conv2D(self.out_filters, (5, 5), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu'))
```

then when creating models

```
layer = column[0](input)
```

Now my question is, how do I save the weights of all the layers in the list?  As far as I know, keras' save function only saves entire models that have been properly built.

**Edit:** Just to clarify, I want to save the "column" list, and not the final models.  I am randomly generating model structures while using the layers stored inside "column".  So 2 models may have different architectures, but they have weights shared (training on one model will also affect the weights of the other model).

Answer (score 0):

like so.

```
model.save_weights('my_model_weights.h5')
```

model.get_weights() can also be used to get the weights of the model, then manually save them to use later

```
model.get_weights()
```

see [Link](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model).

Comment: that's for saving one model though isn't it?
if I have 2 models that have different structures, what happens then? that's why I wanted to save the "columns" list instead of the generated models.

Comment: That is for saving one model, yes. You can use    model.get_weights()   to retreive the weights of a specific model, extract the weights for the layers you need, then save them in some custom format. Then you need to parse that information. I'm unable to find an easier solution for your specific problem at least.